# How to increase hitbox size in ChartJS to trigger hover effects?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

[Make "hitbox" of bar higher in ChartJS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDWWb.png)

On hovering above bar the bar should act as if i was hovering it - change color, show tooltip, etc.

I've tried to use 'chartjs-plugin-stacked100' to solve this problem and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the hover area to extend to the whole height of the chart, you should set `options.interaction.intersect` to `false`:

```js
{
    options: {
       interaction: {
          intersect: false,
          mode: "x"
       }
       // other options ...
    }
    // data, other settings ...
}
```

see docs on [interactions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html) and [samples](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/interactions.html) with different values (albeit for a line chart).